# Пофиксить запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name, ' ', otch_name) as name
```

Трудность в том, что name выводит в конце пробел, в том случаи если поле otch_name пустое.
Возможно ли сразу в запросе пофиксить этот момент. Если 2 последующих поля пусты, то на выходе не должно быть в конце пробелов.

Comment: Trim / switch case... Первая удаляет пробелы, вторая позволяет делать условия.

Answer (score 1):

Функция `TRIM` ([читать здесь](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php)) удаляет все пробелы вначале и вконце строки, соотвественно вас запрос бует выглядеть:
`SELECT *, TRIM(CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name, ' ', otch_name)) as name`

Второй способ, использовать `IF`([ссылка](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php)):
`SELECT *, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name, IF(otch_name IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(' ', otch_name), '')) as name`